# Serialize sodiumoxides' PublicKey into JSON

Tags: serialization, rust, public-key, libsodium

I try to serialize the `PublicKey` struct of sodiumoxide (Rust bindings for libsodium) to a file (e.g. JSON, but binary would be okay, too).

Here is my code:

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate sodiumoxide;

use serde::Serialize;
use serde_json::ser::Serializer;
use sodiumoxide::crypto::sign;

fn main() {
    let (pk, _) = sign::gen_keypair();    
    let pk_ser = serde_json::to_string(&pk);
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
error: the trait bound `sodiumoxide::crypto::sign::PublicKey: serde::Serialize` is not satisfied [E0277]
```

So the compiler tells me that `PublicKey` should implement the serde::Serialize trait. But it does implement `serde::Serialize` as stated here: https://dnaq.github.io/sodiumoxide/sodiumoxide/crypto/sign/ed25519/struct.PublicKey.html

So, what is the problem?

Edit:

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = ...
version = ...
authors = ...

[dependencies]
serde       = "*"
serde_json  = "*"
sodiumoxide = "*"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest available version of `sodiumoxide` on `crates.io` is currently `0.0.10` which doesn't support `serde`. You can see this if you look at the [Cargo.toml file for the 0.0.10 tag](https://github.com/dnaq/sodiumoxide/blob/86351758b9755f0d3e0540ce223427267983a01d/Cargo.toml).

What you can do for now is to use the dependency from github instead of crates.io until they put out a new version. Edit your `Cargo.toml` file like this:

```
[dependencies]
serde       = "*"
serde_json  = "*"
sodiumoxide = { git = "https://github.com/dnaq/sodiumoxide" }
```

Since you're using the version of `sodiumoxide` from github, you'll also need to use the github version of its FFI wrapper `libsodium-sys`. You can do this by adding this to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[replace]
"libsodium-sys:0.0.10" = { git = "https://github.com/dnaq/sodiumoxide/" }
```

Comment: One really needs to know that. I assume most beginners are only using crates.io. Are you interested in writing an issue on GitHub? If not, I will do :-)

Comment: I'll let you do that :)